# How to attach to base event in derived component in Blazor?

Tags: inheritance, events, blazor

In my base component I have single HTML element and I didn't add `onclick` event callback.

How I can attach such handler from derided component level -- i.e. without modifying base component?

**Code**

Simplified by covering 100% my case and the question.

*MyBase.razor*

```
<input/>
```

*MyDerived.razor*

```
@inherits MyBase

@{
  base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}
```

*MyDerived.razor.cs*

```
public partial class MyDerived : MyBase
{
}
```

Comment: Post a small setup of your base and derived classes. So that we know what you mean here.

Comment: @HH done. So far I use workaround, I added virtual callback to base type, so I could override it in derived type.